# specifying :hover of a link with a specific ID

Tags: css

If I had the following:

```
  .nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a:hover
```

and I wanted to specify the same thing for a link 'a' with the id of #futurebutton, how would this look?

Clearly not?:

```
 .nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a#futurebutton:hover
```

Comment: Why would you nest so much to use hover, you can just use #futurebutton:hover{}

Comment: How could I achieve the .open.active and :hover by not nesting and just specifying the single #ID?

Comment: If open and active has sematic meaning here, then you should leverage javascript here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

```
#futurebutton:hover {
    /* styles */
}
```

IDs are unique in the DOM, so you only need to specify the ID as the selector.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, how could I specify .open .active and :hover using just the ID as the selector though?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#futurebutton:hover{
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#futurebutton').open(yourOpenFunction)
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('#futurebutton')`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, in bed with the iPad. Not the best way to type code ;-)